# If the orthogonal complement of any subset of a hilbert space H is closed, doesn't this imply that any subset of H is closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Hi I know that the orthogonal complement of any subset A of H is closed. But then doesn't this imply automatically that A is closed? Since A is orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of A? Thanks..

Edit: By subset I mean subspace.

Comment: all orthogonal complements are closed

Answer (score 1):

No, because it's not true that $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of $A$.  This statement ($(A^\perp)^\perp=A$) is only true if $A$ is a closed linear subspace of $H$.  For instance, of $A$ is a dense linear subspace of $H$ that is not all of $H$, then $A^\perp=0$ so $(A^{\perp})^\perp=H\neq A$.  For an explicit example, consider $H=\ell^2$ and let $A$ be the space of all sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: Oh, isn't it true in R^n ? So its not true in general? Also which statement do you mean is true if A is a closed subspace of H? The fact that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of A is A?Thanks.

Comment: It's true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ since every linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed.  But if $H$ is infinite-dimensional, not every linear subspace is closed.

Comment: Thanks, in your example though, isn't it true that H is the direct sum of A and orthogonal complement of A? Which would just mean A is H in your case?

Comment: No, that's not true.  It's only true that $H=A\oplus A^\perp$ if $A$ is closed.  I would suggest not assuming properties of subspaces you are used to in $\mathbb{R}^n$ hold in infinite dimensions unless you know how to prove them.

Comment: Thanks! so then your saying there might be elements which are not in A and also not in A perp in this case?

Comment: Well, that's always true: the union of $A$ and $A^\perp$ is never $H$ (unless one of them is $H$).  Even when $A$ is closed, most elements of $H$ are a sum of an element of $A$ and an element fo $A^\perp$, not an element of one of them.

Comment: Thanks I guess what I am confused about is the fact that A is dense, the orthogonal complement of A is only the 0 vector which means only the 0 vector and yet H is still not the direct sum of A and A perp. I guess I just have to prove the facts that hold and check those that don't